# Converting date to YYYYMMDD format in SQL Server 2016 from T format

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a date column in a SQL table where the values are stored in the below format.

```
2020-04-07T02:41:49
```

I need to get the date in YYYYMMDD format, like this: `20200407`.

I tried using the below statements but it throws an error on conversion.

```
SELECT
    CONVERT(DATETIME, SUBSTRING(CAST('2020-04-07T02:41:49' AS varchar), 1, 8)) 

SELECT 
    LEFT(4, CAST('2020-04-05T08:05:47' AS nvarchar))
```

Error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Could someone please help?

Thanks.

Comment: If the column is of a string type, improve the schema and use the right data type for it, which would be some date/time type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `try_convert(date,...)`

**Example**

```
Select WithFormat = format(try_convert(date,'2020-04-07T02:41:49'),'yyyyMMdd')
      ,OrNot      = convert(varchar(10),try_convert(date,'2020-04-07T02:41:49'),112)
      ,OrString   = replace(left('2020-04-07T02:41:49',10),'-','')
```

**Returns**

```
WithFormat  OrNot      OrString
20200407    20200407   20200407
```